# Script to change options in MULTIPLE google forms by means of a column in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This question is similar to the last one I presented, but this time, I need to change the options in MULTIPLE google forms with the same title: WHAT IS YOUR NAME (in every single form, the question title is the same, but I have to change the options to hundreds of forms under this question). All the forms must change based on one column in a Google Spreadsheet. The Code below almost works, and I get no errors, but for some reason, it will only change one form instead of changing all of them in the folder. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function updateLists() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID HERE").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId());
   continue;
 }
var items = form.getItems();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
 var item = items[i]
 if (item.getTitle() === "WHAT IS YOUR NAME"){
 var agentList = item.asListItem()
 }
}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var agentValues = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var agentNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++)    
    if(agentValues[i][0] != "")
    agentNames[i] = agentValues[i][0];
 agentList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [logging custom messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#logging_custom_messages) to find out why it's not looking at multiple forms. Likely because `.setChoiceValues()` and some other lines needed aren't inside the `while` loop. `agentNames` could get created once before the while too.

That `continue` statement isn't really doing anything either. The `form` var will only contain the last one looked at. As is, all the form files before the last one are each being placed in the var `form` then replaced with the next one found.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with what Bryan P mentioned above, I changed the script slightly and it finally worked. The modified and working script is below for those who want to copy and paste. Just a quick note: make sure you have nothing else but forms in the folder or an error will be produced.

```
function updateLists() {
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER ID HERE").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId())
var items = form.getItems();
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1){
 var item = items[i]
 if (item.getTitle() === "QUESTION TITLE HERE"){
 var agentList = item.asListItem()
 }
}
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SHEET NAME HERE");
  var agentValues = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getMaxRows() - 1).getValues();
  var agentNames = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < agentValues.length; i++)    
    if(agentValues[i][0] != "")
    agentNames[i] = agentValues[i][0];
 agentList.setChoiceValues(agentNames);
 }
}
```